# Connect 3-wire SPI to ESP32

Tags: spi, dac, esp32

I have an "SPI" 4 channels with the below pinouts, datasheet is [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv5620.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1649356269590&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftlv5620):

[image]

[image]

They say this is an SPI DAC, but from what I remember SPI is the following:

CLK
MOSI
MISO
CS

However the above IC does not seem to have these pins. They say it is a "three-wire serial". I want to connect this IC to the ESP32 uC. Can someone assist me on how to connect this IC to the ESP32 uC?

Comment: You should provide a link to a datasheet for the DAC.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny forgot to use the hyperlink, I added it now

Answer (score 1):

SPI is a name of the module in your MCU, it is an universal interface for easily transmitting synchronous serial data to peripherals with clock and data pins.

And, the DAC has a clock and a data pin, so it is a serial peripheral, and thus compatible with using it with SPI.

So if it only has data in from MCU, but no data out back to MCU, then three wires is all you need since you can't read from it anyway.

The datasheet even provides figures how to access it with 8-bit transactions, so they specifically mention how to access it via standard SPI.

Answer (score 0):

> They say this is an SPI DAC

Who does? SPI is not mentioned in the datasheet.

The serial interface of TLV5620 is similar to SPI, but it's not SPI. The most significant difference is that it uses 11 bits data width, which is not commonly supported by most SPI hardware (usually only 8, 16 and 32b data width is supported).

If your hardware does support 11 bit data width, you could do the following pin mapping, and possibly leverage the SPI hardware:

```
CLK  <-> CLK 
MOSI <-> DATA
CS   <-> LOAD
```

(Although, note that the LOAD signal is active high, CS is usually active low)
There is also the LDAC signal that you may want to use, depending on the application.

To use this DAC from an ESP32, you will likely need to bit-bang the serial interface.

Comment: I think bit-banging will be the easiest, plus they provide the data bitstream. Oh, Digikey says SPI...

Comment: So what if SPI is not mentioned. The chip does not require the SPI interface to support 11-bit transactions. Bit banging is also not required. It will be easiest to just use the SPI interface, because it is meant to interface with all kinds of serial peripherals, and this DAC is no exception. The datasheet even has a diagram how to use it with 8-bit transactions, common to SPI.